# How to find changed values in column

Tags: oracle

I have a table which looks similar to:

| AcctNbr | AcctTypCD | ContractDate | Emp | WrkStLct | WrkStRgn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 12M | 11-01-2021 | John Smith | Downtown | D |
| 10002 | BCK | 11-02-2021 | Jane Smith | Uptown | U |
| 10003 | HPLS | 11-03-2021 | Bob Jones | Midtown | M |
| 10005 | VPLS | 11-04-2021 | Chris Ice | Downtown | D |
| 10006 | CLBV | 11-12-2021 | Smith John | Uptown | U |
| 10007 | TI80 | 11-13-2021 | Joann Penn | Midtown | M |
| 10008 | M360 | 10-04-2021 | Jim Blue | Downtown | D |

My initial query is:

```
Select acctnbr, accttypcd, contractdate, emp, wrkstlct, wrkstrgn
from tableA
where accttypcd in ('HPLS', 'VPLS')
and contractdate between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and sysdate
order by wrkstrgn, wrkstlct, emp, contractdate;
```

End users are requesting now a report which pulls back any time AcctTypCD changes from any value (a list of up to 80+ different values) to either 'HPLS' or 'VPLS' and the emp who made the change, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I apologize in advance for any initial mistakes in this question or if this is a duplicate, first time asking a question.

Comment: Please, provide more context. What is the column with change date? How to partition input data to identify changes? Now you have 8 different accounts, which of course may be of different type.

Comment: I apologize if I don't answer your question as I'm not entirely sure how to answer your questions. If acctnbr 10007 changes from TI80 to HPLS, next time my report runs...I'd like to have the original columns plus columns telling me which employee made the change, the date of that change and what it was prior (anticipating this additional request from them). Any and all accounts which their AcctTypCD changes and those already having the 2 desired AcctTypCDs, should be included in this daily report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to determine fully what you want to achieve given that every row has a different AcctNbr, but your description says "If acctnbr 10007 changes from ...". I will ***assume*** that a change means a new row in the table.  On that assumption, you could do something like

```
Select acctnbr, accttypcd, contractdate, emp, wrkstlct, wrkstrgn,
       lag(accttypcd) over ( partition by acctnbr order by contractdate)
from tableA
where accttypcd in ('HPLS', 'VPLS')
and contractdate between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and sysdate
order by wrkstrgn, wrkstlct, emp, contractdate;
```

where the LAG function will show you the previous value of 'accttypcd' where the definition of "previous" is segmented by acctnbr (the 'partition by' part) and sequenced by contractdata (the 'order by' part).

Analytic SQL (like lag, lead etc) is a big topic, so you can get a full tutorial here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cjxYMxa1e4&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt

Comment: Thanks for this! Just waiting on my end user to make some adjustments on her end and then I'll be able to confirm and mark this as the correct answer.